# Atomic SELECT and subsequent INSERT from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, atomic

Assume I want to update a MySQL database from PHP based on a value just read from the database, in an atomic matter. If I did not need atomicity, I would write, for instance,

```
$Result = mysqli_fetch_all (mysqli_query ($SqlConnection, "SELECT * FROM mytable"), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (some_condition($Result))
    mysqli_query ($SqlConnection, "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (1);");
else
    mysqli_query ($SqlConnection, "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (0);");
```

This is not atomic since the table might have been updated after the `SELECT` statement such that the subsequent `INSERT` statement would do the wrong thing, i.e. based on the old instead of the new state of the table.

I know about `START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT`, but this does not seem to be applicable if I want to do the condition check in PHP. And as I understand, the `SELECT` statement must be completed already in order for PHP to know the result.

However, this does not seem to be a problem specific to PHP since this question would arise in any use case where SQL statements are to be executed from outside of the SQL environment.

Comment: If you can't execute your logic in MySQL... You could [lock the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) for the duration?

Comment: you will need to lock the entire table for this. so better find a way to do your update without select.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use `START TRANSACTION` in this case? As long as you're using the same connection, the transaction persists between calls.

Comment: @Barmar, so this is wrong? "And as I understand, the SELECT statement must be completed already in order for PHP to know the result."

Comment: No, that's not wrong. But it has nothing to do with whether you can use a transaction to make the `SELECT` followed by `UPDATE` atomic.

Comment: `START TRANSACTION` then `SELECT` then read results then `UPDATE` then `COMMIT`.

Comment: @Barmar and it won't help with initial goal. *Consistent read is the default mode in which InnoDB processes SELECT statements in READ COMMITTED and REPEATABLE READ isolation levels. **Because a consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, other sessions are free to modify those tables** while a consistent read is being performed on the table*.